# Magento 2 custom theme - parent inheritance best practice

Tags: magento, e-commerce, frontend, magento2

So, I'm Creating a custom theme with 100% custom design from our designer PSD files. should I be inheriting from Magento/Blank theme or not?

On one hand, it seems almost every tutorial I red is doing it, on the other hand, it seems like **a lot** of work overriding, removing and adding my custom layout and css and a bit of an overkill to load/compile all those unnecessary css/less files.

What is preferred and why?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/  is a better place to ask questions like this

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that